# Get logical result of boolean columns in several rows

Tags: postgresql, boolean-logic

If I have a column which store boolean values, how can I apply OR operator over several rows of that column? I hope I don't have to use joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use postgres [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html) for this, specifically `bool_or` and `bool_and` aggregate functions

```
create table bools (
  a boolean
);

insert into bools values(true), (true), (false);

select bool_or(a) from bools;
```

here is a working example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBoZzyXzF4H28tALVupZfC/1